# unir pruebas fallidas y exitosas

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando en sql server 2012 y tengo dos consultas, la primera me arroja las  pruebas exitosas por numero de pieza, la segunda me muestra las piezas fallidas por numero de pieza y necesito unir esas dos consultas de tal manera que me muestre la pieza y sus respectivos conteos de éxito y fallido. les agrego las consultas y el resultado de cada una. de ante mano muchas gracias.

```
SELECT [Arresters].catalog_number   
      ,(count(case when [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests].[test_passed] ='1'  then 1 else null end)) AS PASADOS
      FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Test_Results LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters ON Arresters.arrester_number=Test_Results.arrester_number   
      LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests] ON Arresters.arrester_number=[Tests].arrester_number   
where [Tests].date_time>'  2019-09-16  ' and [Tests].date_time<'  2019-09-22  '   
and [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests].[test_passed] ='1'   
group by [Arresters].catalog_number

SELECT [Arresters].catalog_number  ,
      count([Arresters].date_time) as fallidos   
      FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Fail_Results LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters ON Arresters.arrester_number=Fail_Results.arrester_number      
    where date_time>'  2019-09-16  ' and date_time<'  2019-09-22  '
    group by [Arresters].catalog_number `
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo usa un UNION ALL para unirlo ya que tienes en ambos dos campos y son del mismo tipo no debe de haber algun problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente, conociendo el modelo, se podría proponer algo mejor, sin embargo lo más simple que te puedo proponer, es partir del "pivote" de la consulta (entiendo) es `Arresters`, y de esta tabla hacer `left join` a las dos consultas que ya tienes por el `catalog_number`:

```
SELECT  A.catalog_number,
        ISNULL(P.PASADOS,0)  Pasados,
        ISNULL(F.fallidos,0) Fallidos
        FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters A
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  [Arresters].catalog_number,
                (COUNT(CASE WHEN [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests].[test_passed] = '1'  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS PASADOS
                FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Test_Results 
                LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters 
                        ON Arresters.arrester_number=Test_Results.arrester_number   
                LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests] 
                        ON Arresters.arrester_number=[Tests].arrester_number   
                WHERE [Tests].date_time > '  2019-09-16  ' 
                        AND [Tests].date_time <'  2019-09-22  '    
                        AND [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests].[test_passed] = '1'   
                GROUP BY [Arresters].catalog_number

        ) P
        ON P.catalog_number = A.catalog_number
        LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT [Arresters].catalog_number,
                count([Arresters].date_time) AS fallidos   
                FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Fail_Results 
                LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters 
                ON Arresters.arrester_number = Fail_Results.arrester_number      
                WHERE date_time > '  2019-09-16  ' 
                      AND date_time < '  2019-09-22  '
                GROUP BY [Arresters].catalog_number         
        ) F
        ON F.catalog_number = A.catalog_number
        WHERE A.date_time > '  2019-09-16  ' 
              AND A.date_time < '  2019-09-22  '      
        GROUP BY A.catalog_number, P.PASADOS, F.fallidos
```

Comentarios:

- El `ISNULL()` lo usamos para los casos dónde el `count` retorne `NULL`, siempre es mejor, en estos casos ver `0`.
- Las consultas están copiadas y pegadas y algo formateadas para mejorar la legibilidad pero conceptualmente lo que se haces es:

  ```
  SELECT T1.catalog_number,
         T2.Pasados,
         T3.Fallidos
         FROM Arresters T1
         LEFT JOIN (Tu consulta 1) T2 ON T1.catalog_number = T2.catalog_number 
         LEFT JOIN (Tu consulta 2) T3 ON T1.catalog_number = T3.catalog_number 
         GROUP BY T1.catalog_number,
                  T2.Pasados,
                  T3.Fallidos
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes 2 opciones en este caso:

- Hacer un UNION a la query, muy probablemente te toque agregar un identificador para saber el tipo de contador, OJO que ambos querys deben retornar la misma cantidad de columnas sino te dara un error.

```
SELECT [Arresters].catalog_number   
      ,(count(case when [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests].[test_passed] ='1'  then 1 else null end)) AS cont, 'PASADOS' as type
      FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Test_Results LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters ON Arresters.arrester_number=Test_Results.arrester_number   
      LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests] ON Arresters.arrester_number=[Tests].arrester_number   
where [Tests].date_time>'  2019-09-16  ' and [Tests].date_time<'  2019-09-22  '   
and [UltraSil].[dbo].[Tests].[test_passed] ='1'   
UNION
SELECT [Arresters].catalog_number  ,
      count([Arresters].date_time) as cont, 'fallidos' as type   
      FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Fail_Results LEFT JOIN [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters ON Arresters.arrester_number=Fail_Results.arrester_number      
    where date_time>'  2019-09-16  ' and date_time<'  2019-09-22  '
    group by [Arresters].catalog_number
```

Ojo que de pronto tienes que arreglarlo por el group by, pero te dejo aca la doc de union: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

- La otra opcion que tienes es realizar subquerys

```
SELECT [Arresters].catalog_number, (subquery a pasados) as pasados, (subquery a fallidos) as fallidos
FROM [UltraSil].dbo.Arresters
where date_time>'2019-09-16' and date_time<'2019-09-22'
```

donde estan los subquery basicamente puedes hacer los querys que ya tienes actualmente.

link de subquerys: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017